# Библиотеки для работы с windows

Tags: python, windows, library

Библиотеки для работы с windows (включить ту или иную программу, включить на этой программе слайдшоу и так далее).

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы запускать программы в windows из python можно использовать функцию system() модуля os

```
import os
os.system('Путь к файлу')
```

Comment: А для того чтобы включить с периодичностью ту или иную программу, какие библиотеки посоветуешь? А так спасибо большое, выручил!

Comment: Окей, я включил программу, а вот например открыв программу PowerPoint, как на ней включить слайдшоу?

Comment: @demon_bach Для периодичности можно в цикл это загнать или в условие, например.
А для того, чтобы включить в PP слайд-шоу можно попробовать порыться в модулях pywinauto и win32api либо на крайний случай pyautogui

Comment: Ты прекрасен! Спасибо!